# How to Configure Terraform AWS Provider?

Tags: terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, aws-devops

I'm trying to create an EC2 instance as mentioned in Terraform documentation.

```
   terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "Acxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  secret_key = "UxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxO"
  region     = "ap-south-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-076e3a557efe1aa9c"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "ExampleAppServerInstance"
  }
}
```

But facing issue ***error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: loading configuration: credential type source_profile profile default***.

I have tried to export cmd and configure the default profile but nothing works for me.

What I'm doing wrong here?

I removed .terraform and and lock.hcl and tried fresh terraform init
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do NOT post code nor errors as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: what is the terraform version you are using ?

Comment: Also check aws cli is working fine or not. Try running "aws s3 ls". Or aws cli commands related to aws ec2.

Comment: If you had previous configuration that didn't work, I'd suggest removing the `.terraform` directory and running `terraform init` again. Also, do you have the `terraform` block with `required_providers` defined anywhere in your code?

Comment: Although this does look like correct configuration, I recommend not configuring credentials in terraform. Consider having terraform expect the environment to already have the access required. That is, set your configuration in shared configuration, then before running terraform `export AWS_PROFILE=some-profile`.

Comment: aws s3 ls cmd working fine. Now trying with V1.0.11. I also tried the latest version.  @mGeek.

Comment: yes did, But no use @MarkoE

Comment: Ok, but the error you posted says the issue is on line 12, while the code you posted does not have the provider definition on line 12. So please update the question if you did something else. Also, you probably should define `required_providers` anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is not the security best practice, But I'm doing it for POC purposes.
I tried export cmd and hardcoded access_key but still facing the issue @theherk

Comment: I have updated the screenshot please have a look @MarkoE

Comment: It seems you also have some kind of a backend configuration, can you add that to the question as well? But please don't add it as a screenshot, rather as a code block.

Comment: I've not configured any backend. I'm only using main.tf file. @MarkoE

Comment: Hi, you need to define a VPC and subnet first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question.

I'd rather go with the following:

1. Configure AWS profile:

```
aws configure
```

or

```
vim ~/.aws/config
```

and then

```
vim ~/.aws/credentials
```

write a new profile name or the default as follows:

*~/.aws/credentials*

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json

[profile TERRAFORM]
region=us-east-1
output=json
```

*~/.aws/credentials*

```
# Sitech
[default]
aws_access_key_id = A****
aws_secret_access_key = B*********

[TERRAFORM]
aws_access_key_id = A****
aws_secret_access_key = B*********
```

2. Use terraform provider profile term rather than access key and secret access key

*main.tf*

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = var.aws_profile
  region  = var.main_aws_region
}
```

*terraform.tfvars*

```
aws_profile     = "TERRAFORM"
main_aws_region = "us-east-1"
```